# Typescript does not let me to write html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am generating a new react app 
`npx create-react-app front-end2 --template typescript` 
but without changing the core, I have this error:

> Type '{ children: Element; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>'.
>
> Type '{ children: Element; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes'.
>
> Types of property 'results' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

for each html element that exist in my return.

My default app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[error in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlNUO.jpg)

What did I tried:

```
-npm install @types/typescript

-npm intall @types/react

-npm intall @prop-types

-delete and re-npm create-react-app...

-npm cache clean --force
```

- I declared jsx as global in my app.tsx and in my react-app-env.d.ts

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'my-html-custom-tag': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
    }
  }
}
```

package.json dependencies part:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.25",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
```

I just have no clue what should I do. If I can give you more information just tell me, thanks.

Comment: Which version of: `typescript`, `@types/react`, and `react` do you have? If not in package.json, then what about package-lock/yarn.lock?

Comment: Can you share package.json file?

Comment: @PrakashT do you need the whole package.json? I am new and I dont know If I should just paste it in the question. There are 40 lines of code.

Comment: yes.This could be better understanding,if you post full package.json file. Also tell how to run this code?

Comment: Ok. you can post only dependencies,scripts part?

Comment: @PrakashT I posted it

Answer (score 1):

I too am using *React built on typescript* and at first I used `tslint` to lint my scripts and boy it was not so fun to configure and fix linting problems. After trying so many days and not making much progress on that, I decided to ditch `tslint` and then started using `eslint` and I just love `eslint`.

After customizing them for a lot of time, I came to an ideal(and stable of course) `eslint` configuration. Follow these steps and you'll love **react typescript** more than anything.

1. Add this packages to your **devDependencies** and install them:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
```

2. This is the **eslintrc.js** file:

```
const status = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? 'error' : 'warn';

module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react-hooks', 'prettier'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'prettier',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
    },
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  rules: {
    // plugin overrides
    'node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt': 'off',
    'react/jsx-first-prop-new-line': [status, 'multiline'],
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 'off',
    'react/jsx-indent-props': [status, 2],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['error', {extensions: ['.jsx', '.tsx']}],
    'react/jsx-max-props-per-line': [1, {'when': 'always'}],
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'react/jsx-space-before-closing': [status, 'always'],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/prefer-interface': 'off',
    // custom eslint overrides
    'arrow-body-style': 'off',
    'camelcase': [
      0, {
        'properties': 'never',
      },
    ],
    'consistent-return': [0, 'never'],
    'import/extensions': [status, 'always', {
      'js': 'never',
      'jsx': 'never',
      'ts': 'never',
      'tsx': 'never',
    }],
    'import/no-named-default': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'indent': [
      status,
      2,
    ],
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    'max-len': 'off',
    'no-console': status,
    'no-debugger': status,
    'no-unused-expressions': [status, {
      'allowShortCircuit': true,
      'allowTernary': true,
    }],
    'no-underscore-dangle': ['off', {'properties': 'never'}],
    'no-useless-escape': 'off',
    'object-curly-newline': 'off',
    'quotes': [
      status,
      'single',
    ],
    'semi': [
      status,
      'always',
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']},
    },
  },
};
```

3. And lastly, this is my **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

That's it. It will track any sort of linting issues as per the typescript standards(*will be your best mate in any projects*). I never created declaration files for any modules until yet. I hope it helps to fix your linting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: "@types/typescript": "^2.0.0", remove this line,

Step 2: Delete node_modules Directory,

Step 3: exec cmd npm install && npm start

This procedure  might be helpful for you